# Java Execute Jar-File NullPointerException when updateLayoutState

Tags: java

i exported my java programm to an executable JAR-File.
When i now run this JAR-File:

```
java -jar myFile.jar
```

this Exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.JList$4.getSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    ....
```

Never saw this before and havent found a solution yet.
What is actually happening here and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seems to be a packaging related issue. It looks more like there is a JList not properly initialized - e.g. like if you passed null as the array in the constructor. So check your code...

Comment: Yes..That might be the problem ..http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4920074

Answer (score 0):

Procedure:

1. Expand the jar in exactly the same location as the jar as a directory, say, `ExpDir`.
2. Run the main class using `-cp ExpDir` and main class.  Use the same current directory, JVM, and everything else.
3. If the program now works (1% probability, in my experience), comment on this on the question.  Also, confirm that you are not inadvertently changing something else.
4. If it does not (99% probability), correct the programming error and/or ask a different question appropriate to the error.